# Why can't I parse this element with htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I can't figure out how to parse the following:

-Example webpage I'm trying to parse: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/255859073.html

-Information I'm trying to get: "7-days". This is the processing time located in the left column of the shipping table.

-The shipping table becomes visible after clicking on the "Shipping and Payment" tab (which is down the page a bit).

So far I have tried selecting the node with different x-path values:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument currentHTML = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 HtmlWeb webget = new HtmlWeb();
 currentHTML = webget.Load("http://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/255859073.html");

 string processingTime = currentHTML.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]").InnerText;
```

and also:

```
 string processingTime = currentHTML.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(concat( \" \", @class, \" \" ), concat( \" \", \"processing\", \" \" ))]").InnerText;
```

But I get this error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I also tried their mobile phone website but they didn't display this information there.

Any idea why this is happening and what I need to do?

Comment: What piece of content are you trying to scrape specifically?

Comment: Hi @cgatian. The content I need here is: "7 days". It is a part of the shipping table in the Shipping & Payment tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your XPath expression was incorrect. Regardless the element you were trying to parse could be better reached by using its Id attribute.  I've modified the XPath expression, and for **bonus** I've added a Regular Expression that will allow you to cleanly parse the days portion from the text.

```
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
        dayParseRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<days>\d)( days\))$");
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument currentHTML = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    HtmlWeb webget = new HtmlWeb();
    currentHTML = webget.Load("http://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/255859073.html");

    //Extract node
    var handlingTimeNode = currentHTML.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"product-info-shipping-sub\"]");

    //Run RegEx against text
    var match = dayParseRegex.Match(handlingTimeNode.InnerText);

    //Convert the days to an integer from the resultant group
    int shippingDays = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["days"].Value);
```

Talk about coding and gettin' paid! Now go rip the hell outta that site!

Comment: Thank you! Nice Regex expressions too. Much appreciated.